# Shortcut to fully specifying package?

Tags: java

Suppose you define a class in a.b.c and you would like to reference a class in a.b. Is there a shortcut to do so, such as ".."?

Comment: Mmm.  Add another namespace reference?  Namespaces aren't cumulative; a.b.c does not include a.b.

Comment: No, you have to import the package using its fully qualified name, there are not such things as relative package names in Java.

Comment: Is that what they call them in Java? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes "package" is what they're called.

Comment: No - there is no "parent package" syntax like `..` in linux command line, xpath, etc.

Comment: ...or the python programming language

Answer (score 1):

no.

Although best practices for java package naming usually involves hierarchical naming, the actual packages defined are not hierarchical and have no relation to one another.